# Push notification Action buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

In my app there is actionable buttons like yes and no buttons in push notification i searched but didn't get any code . give any example of code of objective c iOS 10 push notification with actionable buttons.

Comment: Where you need to add push notification button action ?

Comment: in push notification i have to add two buttons accept/reject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use **UNNotificationServiceExtension** to create **Rich Push Notifications**. You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/CleverTap/notification-examples-ios10/blob/master/notif10objc/NotificationService/NotificationService.m) so that you will get an idea about how to implement it in your app.